# How to insert a string array into mysql json column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I got a problem.When insert a int array into Mysql with JSON Type,we can write a sql like `INSERT INTO table (json_column) VALUES ('[1,2,3]')`.But when I want to insert a string array, I used `INSERT INTO table (json_column) VALUES ("['item1','item2','item3']")`, I was prompted with a error: `3140 - Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value for column 'test.names'.`
What should i do?

Comment: Does this work `VALUES ('["item1", "item2", "item3"]')` ?

Comment: Convert to json and insert into one column or insert in multiple columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON documents have specific rules about format. String values inside a JSON document must be delimited with double-quotes, not single-quotes.

WRONG:

```
"['item1','item2','item3']"
```

RIGHT:

```
'["item1","item2","item3"]'
```

This works nicely inside SQL strings, because SQL strings should be delimited with single-quotes. MySQL is non-standard in supporting double-quotes as an alternative string delimiter.

To ensure creating a JSON document with correct format, you might like to use the [JSON_ARRAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) or [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) functions. You give arguments as individual values, and the function will return a document value, guaranteed to be formatted as valid JSON.

```
INSERT INTO table (json_column) 
VALUES (JSON_ARRAY('item1', 'item2', 'item3'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The statement '["item1","item2"]' is available

Answer (score 0):

Make it more simpler like

```
INSERT INTO table (json_column) VALUES ('["item1","item2","item3"]')
```

Or use key-value pairs like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('{"name": "item1", "id": "item2", "mob": "item3"}');
```